# How to bring user to a route again in react native. I want to refresh a screen completely on button click

Tags: reactjs, react-native

In my application, during video call I want to give the option of "Rejoin". To do so I want to refresh the page or bring user to this route automatically when they click on "Rejoin button"

Comment: What have you tried? What does rejoining consists of?

Comment: If your question is regarding screen navigation you can use `NavigationActions.reset` to a navigation state.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this by using **navigation.reset**

```
props.navigation.reset({
          index: 1,
          routes: [{ name: 'NextScreen', params: { ItemId: myId } }],
        });
```

And I used a timer in useEffect in Next Screen to navigate the user back to previous screen:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  navigation.navigate('PreviousScreen', {
    ItemId: MyId,
  });
}, 3000);
```

}, []);